Generating Excel Chart using powershell and ImportExcel
I need to create some charts using data that already exist in my workbook. Generation of Chart is correct, but axis data is not. It is always numeric, but In some charts i have text or date-time values. After generation, there is no possibility to change type of xAsis
$reportFilePath = "d:\test.xlsx"
$worksheetName = "Trends"
$excelPackage = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $reportFilePath
$worksheet = $excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[$worksheetName]

Add-ExcelChart -Worksheet $worksheet -XRange "A2:A14" -YRange "B2:B14" -ChartType 
XYScatterSmoothNoMarkers -ChartTrendLine Linear -LegendPosition Bottom -SeriesHeader 
'aa' -ShowCategory -TitleBold

# Save and close Excel package
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excelPackage -Show 

In column A i have only date-time values but on XAsis this data is numeric :(

You might want to go directly to the author of ImportExcel. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Solution 1
When investigating the function for Add-ExcelChart, it looks like there is an optional parameter you can enter to format the X-Axis how you would want using the parameter -XAxisNumberformat and specifying Date-Time, which is an option under the Expand-NumberFormat function for the ImportExcel module.
Since the X-Axis is generating as numeric, you should be able to specify it to generate as a date time instead.
Add-ExcelChart -Worksheet $worksheet `
                -XRange "A2:A14" -YRange "B2:B14" `
                -ChartType XYScatterSmoothNoMarkers `
                -ChartTrendLine Linear `
                -LegendPosition Bottom `
                -SeriesHeader 'aa' `
                -ShowCategory `
                -TitleBold `
                -XAxisNumberFormat "Date-Time"

However, if you are trying to change the Excel chart after it is generated, it looks like it isn't possible currently with the module functions. You can recommend it as a new idea under the project on GitHub here: ImportExcel GitHub Idea Page
Source
“Importexcel.” PowerShell Gallery | Public/Add-ExcelChart.Ps1 7.8.9, www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.9/Content/Public%5CAdd-ExcelChart.ps1. Accessed 29 July 2024. 

“Importexcel.” PowerShell Gallery | Public/Expand-NumberFormat.Ps1 7.8.9, www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.9/Content/Public%5CExpand-NumberFormat.ps1. Accessed 29 July 2024. 


I figured out. XYScatterSmoothNoMarkers was a problem. When i change it to Line, everything is correct.
But i have another question. How can i set stylle to trendline? I check documentation, but i didn't find anything
